# running java to make a solution

Tags: java

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  int i;
  String x == str.substring(i);
  int count = 0;
  int len = str.length()-1;
  while (true){
    for (i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
      return (str.charAt(i+1) == 'x');
    }
    return false;
  }
}

 Expected   Run     
 doubleX("axxbb") → true    true    OK  
 doubleX("axaxax") → false  false   OK  
 doubleX("xxxxx") → true    true    OK  
 doubleX("xaxxx") → false   true    X   
 doubleX("aaaax") → false   false   OK  
 doubleX("") → false    false   OK  
 doubleX("abc") → false false   OK  
 doubleX("x") → false   false   OK  
 doubleX("xx") → true   false   X   
 doubleX("xax") → false true    X   
 doubleX("xaxx") → false    true    X   

boolean doubleX(String str) {
  int i;
  //int len = str.startsWith();
  int len = str.length()-1;
  while (true){
    for (i = 1; i < len-1; i++)
    {
      return (str.charAt(i) == 'x');
    }
    return false;
  }
}

Expected    Run     
doubleX("axxbb") → true true    OK  
doubleX("axaxax") → false   true    X   
doubleX("xxxxx") → true true    OK  
doubleX("xaxxx") → false    false   OK  
doubleX("aaaax") → false    false   OK  
doubleX("") → false false   OK  
doubleX("abc") → false  false   OK  
doubleX("x") → false    false   OK  
doubleX("xx") → true    false   X   
doubleX("xax") → false  false   OK  
doubleX("xaxx") → false false   OK
```

I have tried out in many times but can't solve second part.
doubleX("axaxax") -> false which runs true now

I tried to minimize the error, but can't resolve it.
By keeping current code, How could i fix it out?

Thank you

Comment: Which task the function should accomplish?

Comment: first lines of code should give error `int i;
  String x == str.substring(i);`  `i` is not initialized; `==` is comparing, not assigning; all loops are meaningless since always returning at first iteration (`return` (immediately) exits the method also jumping out of any loop)

Comment: if i did int i; then i thought i is already initialized. i hope you to look at the second one, not first one